# How to avoid temp folder clean up on restart Azure VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, temp

After a restart of an Azure Virtual Machine all files in temp folder are deleted.
How can avoid this behavior?

path: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\2

VM size: b1s

OS: Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 4):

That's design as the temp drive is provided by Local Host machine and not from persistent storage.( You are not supposed to save any data in temp drive anything saved will be lost after reboot)

There is an Workaround for this you may refer to this link: https://borncity.com/win/2018/12/27/windows-server-2019-bug-deletes-temp-folder/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Despite I disabled SilentCleanup, after a restart the folder C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\2 is empty.